# Computed vs method inside nested v-for loop according to Vue docs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

On [this page](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Displaying-Filtered-Sorted-Results), it says that:

> In situations where computed properties are not feasible (e.g. inside
> nested v-for loops), you can use a method

However, I am able to use computed props inside a nested v-for loop (check fiddle)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#sample',
  data() {
    return {
      numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    even() {
      return this.numbers.filter(n => n % 2 === 0)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="sample">
  <div v-for="n in numbers">
    {{n}}
    <div v-for="e in even">
      ..{{e}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: In the doc both examples return the same. The “method” option is mentioned to indicate that it is also possible to iterate on the result of a method with v-for. Like the doc says, it is merely useful when working with nested lists (i.e. list dynamically filtered from its parent’s list element). This avoids creating nested computed properties.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I believe the docs mean that computed properties are not feasible inside nested `v-for` loops, if, for instance, *the inner array depends on the current outer array element*.

As a quick example, imagine we want a loop which displays numbers from 1 through 5. And after each number `N`, we need a nested loop which will contain all the whole numbers leading up to the number `N`.

Check fiddle to see what I'm talking about.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#sample',
  data() {
    return {
      numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getLeadingNbs(n) {
     return (Array(n)+'').split(',').map( (n,i) => i )
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="sample">
  <div v-for="n in numbers">
    {{n}}
    <div v-for="l in getLeadingNbs(n)">
      ....{{l}}
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs mean that it is not possible to have a computed for each element of `numbers` because computeds cannot be created dynamically. It is, however, possible to make a computed that returns an array with one value for each element of `numbers`.

Comment: Don't you mean, ...make a _method_ ..., instead of _computed_ ?

Comment: No, you can actually make a computed based on an array, using `map`.

Comment: Gotcha. So I guess a method is necessary whenever the inner loop is computed against a particular value from the outer loop. 

Of the top of my head, an example could be: 
say the outer loop renders `1`, `2`, `3`, and each of the 5 inner loops should display all the natural numbers leading up to that number. So we have

`1 (1)`, `2 (1,2)`, `3 (1,2,3)`

This can't be done simply with computed values, right?

Comment: Right. It becomes impractical.